# Can I bring a suitcase on the Intercity train from Amsterdam to Groningen?

Tags: trains, luggage, netherlands, nederlandse-spoorwegen

I'm traveling to the Netherlands this summer for a week, and I'll be landing at the Amsterdam Airport. To go to Groningen, I'd have to take the Intercity train for 2 hours. Should I buy the tickets in advance, or should I buy them after my arrival?

Also, I'll be bringing one suitcase with me in addition to a huge backpack. Do you think I could bring the suitcase with me on the train, and where can I put it?

Answer (score 8):

There is no advance buying discount for that train but on the other hand, your train ticket will be valid on all trains on that route all day, so no risk in buying before you travel.
Tickets bought online and self printed cost the same as traveling with an OV chipkaart, without the disadvantages of having to buy the pass and keeping value on it.
Tickets bought from a ticket machine cost 1 euro more and from a ticket window 50 cent extra on top of that. So online buying in advance will be cheaper.

You can take your two or more pieces of luggage on the train, take them to your seat (free seat choice, no reservations possible) and store them as best as you can.
Depending on the design of train there will be luggage racks above the seats and/or space between the seat backs or rarely two small spaces at the end of a carriage and a folding seat where luggage can be placed.

Trains in the Netherlands are not build on bringing luggage but do not leave it near the doors while sitting somewhere else, that is a huge theft risk.
Unless you travel on a very busy train there will be space and people will understand your need of keeping your luggage near.

Answer (score 1):

- What you *can* do to lower the costs of the train ride, is to buy the so-called [(NS Flex) *Dal Voordeel*](https://www.ns.nl/nsflex/webshop#/bestelling/producten/2) subscription (which loosely translates as "*off-peak benefit*"): for a price of around 5€ you get a 40% discount on any ticket during off-peak hours (from 9.00 - 16.00, in-between 18.30 and 6.30, and in the weekends and on holidays). Plus, up to four traveling companions get the same discount.
  This subscription can be cancelled after one month, and saves you a whopping €6,06 on this particular ride.
- If you don't mind spending a little more time for a very small gain, you can take advantage of a (seemingly) strange caveat: when buying an international ticket (e.g. from Belgium), buying in advance can save you some money on what is effectively the same route, *even* while you're now buying a ticket for a longer journey:

  | Ticket through [ns.nl](https://ns.nl) for today Amsterdam to Groningen €27.90 | 'Same' ticket through [b-euope.com](https://b-euope.com) *a month later* Noorderkempen (BE) via Amsterdam (CS or Schiphol) to Groningen €25.50 |
  | --- | --- |
  | [image] [image] | [image] |
- Last—and least—it might be worth noting that often (on the most common train models between Amsterdam and Groningen) even large suitcases can be fitted overhead (if their weight allows it :).

Comment: Can you actually get NS Flex without a personal OV-chip? You would have to have the card mailed to a Dutch address, wouldn't you? (My current card predates NS Flex,so perhaps things have changed since I got it.)